# Get programmatically the customizable options selected of the product in an order

Tags: magento2, extensions, order-email

I wrote a custom extension to send an email on success.
I manage to get the details of the products in the order like

```
  $product_name = $_item->getName();
  $product_sku = $_item->getSku();
```

but I cant retrieve the selected customizable options for each one. (For ex color:red...) How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
$options = $item->getProductOptions();        
if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
    foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
        echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
        echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
        echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
        echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work it doesnt give me the selected option